# applescript how to reference objects in containers

Tags: macos, applescript

I'd like to reduce the current system audio volume by 10% on OS X using the Terminal, and `osascript` commands.

I'm doing this:

`osascript -e 'get volume settings'`

Which prints:

`output volume:38, input volume:100, alert volume:100, output muted:false`

I'd like to then do this:

`osascript -e 'set volume 38 - (38 * 0.1)'`

I tried this:
`osascript -e 'first item of (get volume settings)'`

But I get this error:

`0:10: execution error: Can’t get item 1 of {output volume:14, input volume:100, alert volume:100, output muted:false}. (-1728)`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to set the output volume is a bit special

```
osascript -e 'set volume output volume 38'
```

To reduce the output volume by 10% use

```
osascript -e 'set volume output volume (get (output volume of (get volume settings)) * 0.9)'
```